# Image from http will not load in Xamarin iOS Project

Tags: xamarin.forms

I know the has been discussed here before but nothing seems to work for me. I created a new project as a test and added the same image from two sources. One http and one https, I can only get the https one to show. I have edited my Info.plist file and added.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Here is my page.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestImage" x:Class="TestImage.TestImagePage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Image Source="https://www.closersharing.com/Images/Alarm.png"/>        
        <Image Source="http://newhorizonfellowship.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Alarm.png"/>        
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I also changed HTTPClient Implementation to NSURISession (iOS 7+)

I'm at a loss.

Comment: Why are you not using this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58341/ffimageloading-plugin-fast-and-memory-friendly-image-loader-ios-android-forms-windows

Comment: @G.hakim Does FFImageLoader fix the HTTP / HTTPS thing with iOS? I don't see where it will help this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below key to allow all connection.

```html
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
  </dict>
```

Please let me know if it's not working for you.

Comment: Here is my code to bind dynamic image

  <Image x:Name="imgHeader" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Fill" HeightRequest="150"  Aspect = "Fill"></Image>

imgHeader.Source =   new UriImageSource
            {
                CachingEnabled = true,
                Uri = new Uri(eventModel.BannerImage)
            }; 
Please set some height and width as well.
In Info.pList :
<dict>
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

Answer (score 0):

> If your app needs to **load and display web content** from non-secure
>   sites, add the following to your app's Info.plist file **to allow web
>   pages to load correctly** while Apple Transport Security (ATS)
>   protection is still enabled for the rest of the app:
>
> ```
> <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
> <dict>
>   <key> NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
>   <true/>
> </dict>
> ```
>
> Optionally, you can make the following changes to your app's
>   Info.plist file **to completely disable ATS for all domains and internet
>   communication**:
>
> ```
> <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
> <dict>
>   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
>   <true/>
> </dict>
> ```

Source: [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats#opting-out-of-ats)

Since there are no web pages in your example, most probably you meant to use the second example that completely disables ATS. Before seriously considering the second option I would highly recommend to understand the [security risks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/SecureNetworking/SecureNetworking.html).

Beside your original question, maybe it will make sense just to ship the app with the image to avoid complications like this. If you still want to download the images it will make sense to cache them therefor please check [FFImageLoader](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading).

Comment: Neither the NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent or NSAllowsArbitraryLoads works. I cannot include the image with the app. It is coming from a dynamic source.